# How to enable Subversive (Eclipse Plugin) for a project

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using subversive (an eclipse plugin) to connect connect to an SVN repository.  I have only been using it for several weeks but it has been great.

Whenever I create a new project everything works great (see the left side of the image), the project automatically hooks itself up to svn.  When I open a workspace that I had before I installed subversive it does not use the plugin (see the right side of the image).

[image]

I have tried numerous things to try to enable the plugin:

- I looked under all the options under `window -> preferences` (especially the `team` preferences
- I looked under all of the properties under the project (right click the project -> select properties)
- I deleted the workspace folder and created a new one (and re-imported my project)
- I looked at the `.project` file and compared it to a projec that has the plugin enabled but could not see anything relevant there

How can I enable the plugin?  The only way that I have found that works is to checkout the project in a fresh empty folder and then open it in eclipse.  I am trying to avoid this since it will take an hour or so to redownload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project, choose Team - Share project... It should then detect the .svn directories already present and propose you to reuse the SVN information stored inside.

Comment: Thanks!  I say that multiple times but interpreted it as new rather than connect.  Thanks for the help.